# Creating node module with subfolders

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, node-modules

I am developing npm module. I have following index.ts

```
export * from './src/A/index';
```

At this moment, in app import statement looks as follow:

```
import {something} from 'myModule';
```

I would like to add some extra logic to my module, and organize it like:

```
export * from './src/A/index';
export * from './src/B/index';
export * from './src/C/index';
```

What should I write in index.ts to make my module to be used in this way:

```
import {something} from 'myModule/A'
import {something2} from 'myModule/B'
```

etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What should I write in index.ts to make my module to be used in this way

Given that you want to use `import {something} from 'myModule/A'` implies that `myModule/A` folder should have an `index.ts` that exports `something`.

This conflicts with the fact that `A/index` is actually located in `myModule/src/A/index`.

Move the file and it should work.

Comment: Ok. This solution works. I refactored my module. Now I got Module build failed: Error: Typescript emitted no output for. How should I prepare my index files/package.json?